# How to pass data to UI thread

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

Good evening.

I have an activity like this. In handleMessage I have access to largeText field and can change it, but I can't do smth  whith stringLinks field, or each other field which is not a UI element(like TextView, Button, EditText, etc).
How can I add to stringLinks ?

```
public class AboutUsActivity extends Activity {

Handler h;
TextView largeText;
List<String> stringLinks;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    stringLinks = new ArrayList<String>();  
    largeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    h = new Handler() {

        public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
            HtmlParser parser;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                parser = new HtmlParser(String.valueOf(msg.getData()));
                List<TagNode> links = parser.getContentByClassName("ab");
                for (Iterator<TagNode> iterator = stringLinks.iterator(); iterator
                        .hasNext();) {

                    TagNode divElement = (TagNode) iterator.next();
                    result.append(divElement.getText().toString());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            largeText.setText(newhtml);       //Work
            stringLinks.add(newhtml);               //doesn't work
        }

    };

    MyHttpClientUsage connect = new MyHttpClientUsage(h);
    try {
        connect.getInfoAbout();
    } catch (HttpException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried something like runOnUiThread(Runnable action)?

Comment: Where does newhtml come from? There's no declaration anywhere for it. And as someones answer said (who deleted it for some reason), your 'links' variable is not accessible outside of your try/catch statement

Comment: newhtml comes from connect.getInfoAbout() and it sends right, cause largeText.setText(newhtml) works.

Comment: I want to add to stringList which accessible outside try/catch. Sorry for mistake in question.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know if I understood you correctly.

If i did, you can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class

Check out their main too methods, doInBackground that executes something in a separate thread and onPostExecute that runs in UI Thread. They can comunicate with each other passing objects, and you can also publish the progress of your task.

It really looks like SwingWorker (maybe you used it if you programmed Swing applications).